# How to disable modal of dialog in android?

Tags: android, android-dialog

i want to show dialog (not alert dialog) but i don't want dialog show modal.

How to set dialog to show modal or not?

this is my code

```
Dialog dialog = new Dialog(CategoryList.this);
dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
dialog.setContentView(actionview);
dialog.show()
```

Comment: do you want to use Toast instead then?

Comment: By non-modal do you mean the dialog is part of the screen and all all visible parts are able to be interacted with? You should probably defined your dialog as part of your layout.

Comment: @user2310289 in my actionview is has a button when i use Toast a button onclick event is not work. then i change to use dialog.

Comment: @MazeHatter Can you show me an example? sorry i'm little english skill.

Comment: Try to mock up how you want the screen to look. Use an image editor to make an image that represents how you want the screen to look. Post that image here. PopupWindow is a good answer too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use PopupWindow instead, and setOutsideTouchable(true).
or try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4132699/timed-modeless-dialog)