# Show AlertDialog without hiding ActionBar

Tags: java, android, android-actionbar

I'd like to show an Alert Dialog which does not hide action bar. Is it possible to do it? The code which I tried is:

```
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(activity);

    builder.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
    builder.setTitle("Basemap selection");
    builder.setSingleChoiceItems(new String[]{"Create cache", "Use existing file"}, 0, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            //Some logic here.
        }
    });
    builder.setNegativeButton(R.string.common_cancel, null);
    builder.create().show();
```

It covers the whole screen but I need the action bar to be available while dialog is showing. I know that it might violate some android rules but UX department wants it.
The screenshot is:[image]

Comment: Post your code what u tried?

Comment: one option is to make the activity to alert dialogue. its simple create a activity and go to manifest and set the activity theme as @android:style/Theme.DeviceDefault.Dialog

Comment: What do you mean by this?  When you show an Alert Dialog, it will appear above the current Activity - is the Activity Action Bar what you want to hide/show?  Or do you want to show the Action Bar in the dialog's view itself?

Comment: You may implement dialog as activity for the same, with this you can show the action bar.

Comment: @ shylendra how is it possible ?

Comment: "You may implement dialog as activity for the same" - yes I can but a user needs to ineract with map sometimes. In this case I need to maintain action bar in 2 activities.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to make a non-modal dialog (allowing the user to tap outside the dialog and access the Action Bar while the dialog is visible), there's some information here that may be helpful: [timed modeless dialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4132699/timed-modeless-dialog), specifically the use of `dialog.getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL);` - called after your dialog is visible.

Comment: It seems this is what I'm looking for. I need to try this.

Comment: Let me know if it doesn't work for you, and if it does, please mark the answer as accepted to help future visitors to this page.

Answer (score 0):

The option is to change the activity to the Dialogue.Its simple process create an activity and goes to manifest file and set the theme of activity as

```
@android:style/Theme.DeviceDefault.Dialog
```

Comment: I tried, it does not work, maybe I've done something wrong. The code is <activity android:name=".activities.main.MainActivity" android:label="@string/app_name" android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.DeviceDefault.Dialog"</activity>

Comment: u have to create a new activity for the dialogue example:BaseMap Selection.java, change the theme in this activity to the @android:style/Theme.DeviceDefault.Dialog. when u want show popup, u have to call the activity by using intent

Comment: Aaah. Do you want to say that this new activity will not hide action bar of the previous one?

Comment: yes. This is the way.The dialogue comes over the activity. Other wise u have to create a custom dialogue.