# How to make a non-modal sheet using BottomSheetDialog in .NET MAUI?

Tags: c#, .net, maui, android-bottomsheetdialog

I have a method that creates a bottom sheet using BottomSheetDialog in a .NET MAUI app. The code looks something like this:

public static BottomSheetDialog ShowBottomSheet(this Page page, IView bottomSheetContent)
{
var bottomSheetDialog = new BottomSheetDialog(Platform.CurrentActivity?.Window?.DecorView.FindViewById(Android.Resource.Id.Content)?.Context ?? throw new InvalidOperationException("Context is null"));
bottomSheetDialog.SetContentView(bottomSheetContent.ToPlatform(page.Handler?.MauiContext ?? throw new Exception("MauiContext is null")));
bottomSheetDialog.Window?.ClearFlags(WindowManagerFlags.NotTouchable);
bottomSheetDialog.Window?.ClearFlags(WindowManagerFlags.DimBehind);
bottomSheetDialog.Window?.ClearFlags(WindowManagerFlags.NotFocusable);
bottomSheetDialog.Window?.AddFlags(WindowManagerFlags.SplitTouch);
bottomSheetDialog.Behavior.FitToContents = true;
bottomSheetDialog.Behavior.Draggable = true;
bottomSheetDialog.Behavior.SkipCollapsed = true;
bottomSheetDialog.SetCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
bottomSheetDialog.Show();
return bottomSheetDialog;
}

This method creates a modal bottom sheet. I want to modify it to create a non-modal bottom sheet, i.e., a sheet that doesn't block interaction with the underlying UI. How can I achieve this?
I've tried adjusting the Behavior properties such as FitToContents, Draggable, and SkipCollapsed etc, but I haven't been able to make it non-modal.

Any help or guidance on how to modify this code to create a non-modal bottom sheet would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You may tried ```bottomSheetDialog.Window?.AddFlags(WindowManagerFlags.NotTouchModal);bottomSheetDialog.Window?.AddFlags(WindowManagerFlags.WatchOutsideTouch);```

Comment: I have tried that but it did not work

Comment: You may also refer to this thread: [timed modeless dialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4132699/timed-modeless-dialog), which creates  a modeless dialog.